# Git pull not updating, repo inconsistent?

Tags: git, apache, webdav, git-pull

I have a strange problem with git configured using DAV on apache2.

I'll provide more details, if needed, but here is a high-level overview of the problem.

I have 3 clones of a repository:

1. the bare one to push and pull from
2. one on Machine A
3. one on Machine B

I do 1 last change on Machine A, and I pushed all my changes, and did a pull on both. The problem is, for some reason I don't see my last changes after pulling on Machine B.

There is no message about being ahead of remote on either machine either.

The weird part is:

- If I do a "git log" on the bare repository, the last changes from Machine A will be there
- If I do another clone of the bare repository, the changes won't be there. It will only be up to the last changes that Machine B sees.

Is this a server configuration issue or a git issue? I've had this problem for many months now.

`git branch -a` prints:

Machine A:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Machine B:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

`.git/config` for both:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = false
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
  url = http://<url>/p/home.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: What does `git branch -a` print?

Comment: are the .git/config files the same for both A and B?

Comment: yes, the .git/config are the same

Comment: Have you set up a post-update hook on your bare repository to run git-update-server-info?

Comment: instead of `git pull` have you tried `fetch`ing and `merge`ing manually?

Comment: @Mark Longair Ah! that was the problem. Why is this not enabled by default?

Comment: @verhogen I'm not sure, but I'd guess it's just that since the HTTP based transports are seen as the third choice after SSH and the git protocol, it wouldn't be desirable for every server to take the hit of running git update-server-info on every push by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've confirmed my guess was right in the comments, I'll add this as an answer :)  It sounds like the problem is the one described in this git FAQ:

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#My_HTTP_repository_has_updates.2C_which_.27git_clone.27_misses._What_happened.3F

There's a sample hook called post-update.sample in .git/hooks/ that you can rename to post-update in order to automatically run `git update-server-info` after a push.  This generates information needed by the dumb HTTP transport.

Comment: That link to kernel.org is broken, the page is here now: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/g/i/t/GitFaq_ebc3.html#My_HTTP_repository_has_updates.2C_which_git_clone_misses._What_happened.3F